# How do I make my custom targets run only when ant release is run?

Tags: android, ant, build-tools

I have a standard android generated build script. My `custom_rules.xml` build script.

```
<project>

    <target name="-minify" >
        // More code here
    </target>
    <target name="-modify-index-html" >
        // More code here
    </target>

    <target name="-post-compile" depends="-minify"/>

    <target name="-post-package" depends="-modify-index-html"/>

</project>
```

The problem is I do not want targets `-minify` and `-modify-index-html` to run when `debug` build is being run. In fact they must run only when `release` target is run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found my solution.

Both my custom targets will be executed after `-set-release-mode` is run (in case of release). So, here it goes:-

```
<target name="-minify" if="isReleaseTarget">
    ...
</target>

<target name="-modify-index-html" if="isReleaseTarget">
    ...
</target>

<target name="-set-release-mode" depends="android_rules.-set-release-mode">
    <property name="isReleaseTarget" value="true"/>
</target>
```

Notice that I override the android provided `-set-release-mode` target and make it depended on the actual target. However, it sets the property `isReleaseTarget`. I use that on my custom targets to make sure they run only when this is set.